# How do I get the selected object during bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre callback while rendering?

Tags: python, rendering, add-on

I would like to import an OBJ file, find its mesh object, and get its name. I'd like to do this during the bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre callback function. I have the following code, which is not working:

```
directoryPath = "C:\some\path\to\my\directory"
def load_mesh(dummy):
    frameNumber = bpy.scene.frame_current
    filePath = os.path.join(directoryPath, "someFile_" + frameNumber + ".obj")

    # import the file
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = filePath)

    # get the recently-imported and hopefully-selected object
    currentMesh = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

    meshName = currentMesh.name_full

# add my callback function
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(load_mesh)
```

When I render an animation (Ctrl+F12), it's able to load the .OBJ file, but when I try to access `bpy.context.selected_objects[0]`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'` By contrast, this code works fine if I simply play the animation in the timeline.

I did a little investigation to see what attributes `bpy.context` has access to. It looks like it can access everything in the [Global Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#global-context) (including `collection` and `scene`) as well as `bl_rna`, `copy`, `evaluated_depsgraph_get`, and `rna_type`.

How do I get a list of selected objects from within a render_pre handler callback function? Or just the object that was just imported?

Blender 2.82